# App Service plan doesn't list all apps in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I am working with Azure functions. They are all put under the same App Service plan. However, when I go to the Overview section of the said App Service plan, the "App(s) / Slots" value is "4 / 0". If I click on this, only 4 of the Function apps are listed, whereas I would expect all of them to be listed. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: how many functions you have?

Comment: Somewhere around 10

Comment: did you choose consumption plan or appservice plan?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was consumption. Do you know where I can check this to be sure?

Comment: did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have created the function App on different plans, you can navigate to each of the apps and see it in the overview. In this case each of the funciton will have its own consumption plan.

[image]